# web3.eth.getProof Merkle Patricia Proof Verification

Tags: web3js, storage, merkle-patricia-tries

I am trying to verify a proof that a contract has some value stored at a specified key using the contracts storage root and a proof received from a web3.eth.getProof call. Here are the results:

```
storageHash: '0x030748d1533b7bd4a22bba317ba2caa7c244bcbdb5671b95c324766a19edbdbd',
storageProof: {  
     key: '0x2',  
     value: '0x24ffaf4fd513facfcd1461d1ab0ddd43bb9ca373',  
     proof: [  
     '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',  
     '0xf891a0763902fd427b8f29c5f26e793ad3ea6705b120edef718690f785bd1ee1e404258080808080a01a08e4a438b60cca94c89097eb98f85782a124e8ebdfcee7f4697af0a9b4d441808080a0cbc0156d648e34e4a2405a4f68bc44e2071992077bf0cce9ef0394fc0ed5d11f80808080a00a39726d15dd00726445876325da5f10fdc05e5f9884d59e10cbd23a5664969e80',  
     '0xf8518080808080a0fbf384e26e9ea66e28445ee01b9cc85c31496158d390bf17a42d35ad559a6e7480a0055de1019e7abe1a23cffb7a102e8cbe19d1c5e2dc8253022439355a1a55a852808080808080808080',          
     '0xf69f3787fa12a823e0f2b7631cc41b3ba8828b3321ca811111fa75cd3aa3bb5ace959424ffaf4fd513facfcd1461d1ab0ddd43bb9ca373'  
        ]  
      }  
    ]
```

I am not sure why the proof includes 4 nodes when the key is only 1 nibble long. Could someone explain how to verify this proof and how exactly it was constructed?

It looks like (from putting the proof nodes in a trie, that the data `9424ffaf4fd513facfcd1461d1ab0ddd43bb9ca373` is stored under key `405787fa12a823e0f2b7631cc41b3ba8828b3321ca811111fa75cd3aa3bb5ace`. Not exactly sure how to interprest this as the data I'm looking for is the fixed size (obviously) address `24ffaf4fd513facfcd1461d1ab0ddd43bb9ca373` under storage key `2`. Pretty confused...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The full key is "0x00.....02". it has 32 bytes, but to minimize the storage in leveldb, it trim the redundant zeros.
2. You can put the content proof to python rlp package to see what happened, like `rlp.decode(proof.stoargeProof[0])`. The proof array is rlp-encoded trie node.